# Angular Material Styles Not Appearing in Storybook

Tags: angular-material, angular-cli, storybook, nrwl-nx, angular-storybook

I am trying to create a Storybook using the Angular Material library in an `nx` app but I can't get the styles to appear that come along with the library. So the component renders but there are no styles along with it. I've added the component to Storybook like so:

```
export default {
  title: 'Buttons',
  component: ButtonComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [
        MatButtonModule
      ],
    }),
  ]
} as Meta<ButtonComponent>;
```

This screenshot shows the Primary Button but doesn't get the correct purple styling.

[image]

How do I go about getting something like this import into Storybook so the theme comes through?

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

This is also an `nx` app so there is no `angular.json`, but a `project.json` and a `workspace.json`. I have try adding the theme to `project.json` as I have below but doesn't work, I would assume it needs to passed to storybook directly somehow and not inside of the project.json (which would apply to the app itself and not storybook)?

```
"build": {
      "options": {
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    },
```

Using `Angular Material "13.2.3"`, `"@nrwl/storybook": "13.8.3"`, and then these additional libraries:

```
"@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.5.0-alpha.41",
"@storybook/addon-knobs": "6.4.0",
"@storybook/addons": "^6.5.0-alpha.41",
"@storybook/angular": "6.5.0-alpha.41",
"@storybook/api": "6.5.0-alpha.41",
"@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.5.0-alpha.41",
"@storybook/core-server": "6.5.0-alpha.41",
"@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.0-alpha.41",
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

In your `project.json` there should be a `storybook` target. That's where you need to add styles.

`build` only affects the build target.

e.g.

```
   "storybook": {
      "executor": "@storybook/angular:start-storybook",
      "options": {
        "port": 4400,
        "configDir": "libs/shared/form-controls-ui/.storybook",
        "browserTarget": "shared-form-controls-ui:build-storybook",
        "compodoc": false,
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css"
        ]
      },
```

Comment: I had ../node_modules and I had to change it to ./node_modules.  Notice the double dot to single dot difference

Comment: My answer seems to be the cause of a uncaught TypeError. Storybook runs with theming but error appears in console

Comment: This is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a little bit too late but here is what I've done.

I've created a styles.scss file in the root of the project, inside it I've imported
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

and then I've imported it into scss of the component.

You can skip the scss in the root and 1just import material into the component's scss.

Cheers!